# Как пофиксить баг на gmail, не правильное отображение сгенерированного кода?

Tags: javascript, php, gmail

Отправляю по почте сгенерированный на js код, когда на gmail приходит письмо то отображает его совсем не вменяемо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

путем проб и ошибок я вычислил что баг этот если взять html который выдал js, выровнять его с переносами строк , то все идеально отображается.

Если я отправляю html в виде текста то выходит вот такая штука
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

толи гугл переводит строку и в этот момент косячит , толи ему нужно какой то символ переноса строки специальный...
Как видите в коде у меня это только в нескольких местах , а код полностью весь одинаковый и генерируется в цикле так что проблема не в кодировке , а в переносах строки

как мне побороть этот баг? У кого есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

удалось пофиксить баг переносом строк \n